# Get max term and number

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I did a map reduce which counts the terms of book titles and counts them using scala. I want to output both the term and the number but only get the number using:

```
println("max term :" +wordCount.reduce( (a,b)=> ("max", a._2 max b._2))._2)
```

I was wondering how I also include the term.

Thank you

Example:

("The", 5) 
("Of", 8)
("is", 10)
…

my current code gives me the maximum number but I don't know how to get the term in.

Initial code:
val inputPR2Q1

```
val inputPR2Q1 =  sc.textFile("/root/pagecounts-20160101-000000")
val titlecolumn = inputPR2Q1.map(line => line.split(" ")(1))
val wordCount = titlecolumn.flatMap(line => line.split("_")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_ + _);
```

Here I just take a file containing book titles with other data. I take book titles alone and do a MapReduce to count and sum each term in the titles separately.

Comment: What is the type of `wordCount` can you give us some example input and expected output? What should happen if multiple elements have the max count? Is this done using plain **Scala** or **Spark**?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez added an example, my current code just gives me the max number, and I want to also have the term corresponding it.

Comment: You didn't answered any of the questions. It is too hard to help if everything is so cryptic.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.sortBy` with `ascending=false` and `take(1)` on RDD

```
sc.textFile("/root/pagecounts-20160101-000000").
map(line => line.split(" ")(1)).
flatMap(line => line.split("_")).
map(word => (word,1)).
reduceByKey(_ + _).
sortBy(_._2,ascending=false).
take(1)
```

Comment: So, your answer is basically exactly the same as mine, without any added value?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you take a look to the [**scaladoc**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD).
You can just use `sortBy`.

```
val (maxTerm, count) = wordCount.sortBy(_._2, ascending = false).take(1).head
```

Comment: .maxBy is giving me this error: error: value maxBy is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)]

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, `soryBy`, my bad.

Comment: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: Array[(String, Int)]
       val (maxTerm, count) = wordCount.sortBy(_._2, ascending = false).take(1)
Error at val (maxTerm, count)

Comment: @Daniel Oh right, I see the problem, I have edited the answer. Sorry.